# Flattening a 2D array to use map/reduce

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I have been trying to get better at functional programming, which includes understanding map/reduce. I wrote a function intended to fill an autocomplete with values. The challenge I was encountering was my Mongo records, which had a category array that needed to be flattened for the autocomplete to work. Being a novice, I somehow came up with this code, and it works. But I know there must be a better way to do it using map/reduce.

You will see cats stores a call that uses `.map`, but it's the code from the package example and I have no idea what it does.

```
      categoryTypeAheadVals: function() {
    cats = Todos.find({}, {categories: 1}).fetch().map(function(it){ return it.categories; });
    y = [];
    var x = cats.forEach(function(it) {
      it.forEach(function(it){
        y.push(it);
      });
    });
    return y;
  }

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**New**

This code can actually be further reduced by using JavaScript's `apply`:

```
y = y.concat.apply(y, cats);
```

The above line will merge all the arrays inside the `cats` array into a single array and then copy it into `y`.

This is better than the solution you already have because:

1. It is faster. No more looping over two arrays.
2. It is easier to read. If you want, just slap a comment on this line and it is very easy to understand.

---

**Old**

> ```
> it.forEach(function(it){
>     y.push(it);
> });
> ```

This section is over-done. All you are doing is copying the array `it` into `y`, and JavaScript already has a built in function for that: [Array.prototype.concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat).

You can use this function to copy one array into another.

Now, your code becomes this:

```
var x = cats.forEach(function(it) {
    y = y.concat(it);
});
```

Comment: I gave this a try, but it did not seem to work.   I think im implementing it incorrectly.  I wiped out:

        y = [];
    var x = cats.forEach(function(it) {
      it.forEach(function(it){
        y.push(it);
      });
    });

and replaced with:

    y = y.concat.apply(y, cats);
    var x = cats.forEach(function(it) {
    y = y.concat(it);
});

Originally, I thought I just need the line with apply, but I got a y is undefined.   So I added the 2nd line, and got a y is undefined.   Then I added both, and still got undefined.

Any suggestions?

Comment: @TaylorAckley Perhaps you'd like to talk in chat?

Comment: I actually just got it to work, had a rookie mistake.   I used just the apply line and had a typo.  Now it works great.  I appreciate the schooling!

Comment: @TaylorAckley No problem! Glad I could help out.